# Did Euler produce any Russian text?

Tags: mathematics, mathematicians, euler, 18th-century

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leonhard_Euler), Euler (1707-1783) "mastered Russian and settled into life in Saint Petersburg" in 1727. Did he produce any text in Russian, either mathematical or personal?

On [The Euler Archive](http://eulerarchive.maa.org), I can only find writings in Latin, German, and French (maybe I just did not search hard enough).

Comment: You mean a mathematical text? Then unlikely: There was no audience for that.

Comment: The Russian wikipedia asserts that Euler published "some works" in Russian. "Универсальная арифметика" was published first in Russian in 1768-9 but it has been written is German and in 1770 appeared in the original language as "Elements of Algebra".  This is easily discoverable but further items are not so quick to come in search.

Comment: Certainly he did not produce any scientific text. At that time, Russian was not used for science. Proceedings of the Imperial Academy, the only scientific journal published in Russia at that time had a rule: papers in mathematics should be in Latin, in all other sciences - in French. The rule is stated in the introduction to the first volume.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, Euler wrote letters in Russian:
[image]

(Euler's letter to Nartov, June 18, 1743)

Interestingly, he signed papers as "Леонгардъ Эулеръ", a direct transliteration of his name, not how he is called in Russian today (imitating pronunciation).